# 2D semmi-dynamic array strange syntax mystery

Tags: c++

I don't quite understand what exactly this is.  I've searched on web and stacked and I'd love a clear explanation.

```
const size_t rows = 3;    //row size can be dynamic (runtime det)
const size_t cols = 3;
int (*data)[cols] = new int[rows][cols]{{1,2,3,},{4,5,6},{7,8,9}};
```

You can access it like a 2D array:

```
data[i][j]
```

But you have to pass it to a function as:

```
void func(int (*data)[3], const size_t rows)
```

or

```
void func(int data[][3], const size_t rows)
```

but not as

```
void func(int **data, const size_t rows, const size_t cols)
```

So you would think it is a 2D array.  It's cell addresses are contiguous.

But... when you delete it, you delete it like so:

```
delete[] data;
```

not

```
for(size_t r=0; r<rows; r++)
    delete[] data[r];
delete[] data;
```

This deletion implies it is not a 2D array.  Since we are deleting just a row.  If you try to delete with for loop, you'll get a crash.

I'm hoping someone can shed light on what exactly this is.  The syntax is very strange.

In particular, the (*data) syntax is unclear to me. What is this exactly?  (*data) does not equal *data.  That is, *data does not work for some reason.

Comment: Pointers are not arrays, arrays are not pointers.

Comment: _"If type is an array type, __all__ dimensions other than the first must be specified as positive ..."_ see:http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/new

Comment: Think of it as 1D array of objects, where each object is `int[3]` (an array of three `int`s). C++ doesn't really have 2D arrays - it only has arrays whose elements may in turn happen to be arrays.

Comment: The fact that you delete it with a single `delete[]` means only that it was created with a single `new[]`, nothing more. Your deletion snippet is not connected with 2D arrays in any way. It's used for deleting so-called *jagged arrays*, i.e. arrays of arrays in which each subarray may have a different size.

Comment: ok, so as Igor said, it is internally really a 1D array where each cell is an array.  Now, I just wish someone could explain what is the difference between (*data)[] and *data[].

Comment: why do we have to surround *data with brackets? I don't understand what that does.

Comment: It's due to operator precedence.  `(*data)[]` is different from `*(data[])`, and since the `[]` operator has a higher precedence, the expression is interpreted the same as `*(data[])`.

Comment: okay... correct me if i'm wrong.  int (*data)[cols] = new int[rows][cols] means: a cols sized array of pointers to int where data point to the first item?  It just doesn't make any sense to me.  namely cause array is not cols size but rows x cols size.  Does anyone know how to read this?

Comment: `int (*data)[3]` is a pointer to an `int[3]`. This is to what array `int data[4][3]` decays e.g. if passed to a function as argument. The parentheses doesn't allow an "intuitive" interpretation. It's as already said: The parentheses shall prevent that `[]` is applied to `data` before `*`. (Otherwise it would be an array of `int*`). I must admit this is brain-twizzling. (I needed long until I got it. At least, I believe I got it...)

Comment: I once read a statement like this: "You've have to read it from inside to out." May be this helps: [`int (*data)[3]`](https://cdecl.org/?q=int+%28*data%29%5B3%5D) vs. [`int *data[3]`](https://cdecl.org/?q=int+*data%5B3%5D) if in doubt (and you may use the linked site as well to translate from (a subset of) English to C as well).

Comment: Schef, thanks so much! :) So data is a pointer to an array of ints with 3 cells.  This is what I find confusing because like I said, or I should say Igor said, the syntax reads like that...but we know the array is not size 3 and we also know that the cells are not 3 ints, but instead 3 sub-arrays.  To add further to the confusion, int (*data)[3] = new int[4][3]; isn't even 3 sub-arrays (even tho it reads as so) it is actually 4 sub-arrays.  Am I being obtuse or did the C++ committee drop the ball on this one. This syntax seems to mislead. What you read it as is not what it is under the sheets.

Comment: They should have made the syntax int (*data)[4][3] = new int[4][3];  Then it would read, "4 by 3 array pointed to by data where each cell is comprised of ints."  Or, "array of size 12 pointed to by data where each cell is an int".  Clear and concise.  Instead int (*data)[3] = new int[4][3]; read as, "array of 3 elements pointed to by data where each cell is an int".  That is misleading in 3 ways.  Size is not 3 nor are the types of each cell ints but 3 sub-arrays... nor is it really 3 sub-arrays but actually 4.  Just my thoughts.  Please correct me if I'm mistaken.